# Can't set footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm currently working on a website and I'm getting crazy about this footer that won't stay at the bottom of the page. I already checked other topics with the same problem and nothing solved mine.

When I try "relative" the footer goes under the "topbox" (which is my header) and when I try "absolute" it goes in the middle of the page.

```
 <header>
 <div class="topbox">
 <ul>
 <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </header>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="scrollbtn"><img src="Images/Scroll.png" style="width:40%"/>     
</div>
<div class="bgbox">
<div class="box2">
<a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">© 2017 "TEXT" All Rights Reserved</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So here we have TOPBOX which is the header, Wrapper, scrollbtn (a pic of a mouse to indicate need to scroll), bgbox (background of the content), box2 (content), the "lorep ipsum" is the content and is very long which makes the user scroll. That's my problem, the footer is at the bottom of the page when you load it and thus in the middle of it when you scroll down.

Here is the CSS :

```
 body, html {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: #060b0f;
 padding:0%;
 background-image: url('../images/background3.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 /* HEADER */
 .topbox {
 margin:0%;
 position: fixed;
 top:0%;
 left: 0%;
 width:100%;
 z-index:999;
 text-align:center;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding:0%;
 font-family:Impact;
 font-size:20px;
 }
 .topbox ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0%;
 padding: 0%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #459cfe;}

 .topbox li {
 display: inline;
 }
  .topbox li a {
 display: inline;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 .topbox li a:hover:not(.active) {
   background-color: #397fcd;
 }
.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
/*HEADER FIN*/
.scrollbtn {
position: absolute;
bottom : 0%;
left: 49%;
}

.hot {
color:#4080e1;
}
.box2 {
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:10%;
 width : 70%;
 opacity:1;
 color: black;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:4;

 background-color:transparent;


 }
 .box2 a{
 opacity:1;
  }
 .bgbox {
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:8%;
 padding: 5%;
 padding-left: 8%;
 width : 70%;
 position: absolute;
 top : 10%;
 left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);     
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:3;


 }
 .bgbox:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);  
 }

 #footer {
 font-size:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 left:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 background-color: #459cfe;
 }
.wrapper {
 height:100%;
 }
```

I've tried so many different things (changing body height, wrapping everything, relative, absolute, fixed, static, ...) that I can't think of anything else. I need an exterior point of view.

Comment: The 'topbox' must be inside the body tag. Am not saying this is a fix but just pointing out that issue or is it typo

Comment: No it's not a typo but it didn't seem to be a problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to position your footer according to the bottom of a parent element.  So you must give it a position:absolute

It will find the nearest parent that isn't "static" to position itself relative to.  So currently it'll sit at the bottom of "body".  If you want it to sit at the bottom of ".wrapper", give .wrapper a position of "relative"

EDIT: OK I see the problem with "bgbox" going beyond "header".

1.
Remove all "height 100%" - that sets the height to be the same as the viewport (visible are)

2.
Your "bgbox" is currently positioned absolute - so it won't be "pushed down" by other content, and it won't push other content down as it gets bigger.  I'm not sure what you intend here.  Do you want "bgbox" to be part of the regular content of the page?  In that case, make it position:relative.  (I think you don't want other content occupying the same space as bgbox, since you have text in it.  Your css and the "bg" in the name makes me think maybe you copied a template from somewhere but misunderstood the original intention of bgbox?)

Side note:  You've got some HTML outside the body tag.  I think you're confused between "head" which is a section of HTML describing the page, and potentially linking to resources, and "header" which is just a DIV with semantic information used by e.g. search engines.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it right away but no I'm not confused with "Head" it's just that I put it outside by error and it worked so I prefered it that way as it looks cleaner to me

Comment: I tried by just adding "position:relative" to wrapper and the footer just dissapeared ><

Comment: wrapper to position:relative was an optional second step.  Please see my first sentence: set footer to position:absolute

Comment: "Bgbox" is the background of "Box" wich is supposed to be the content (lorep ipsum...). I needed this to have a 0.5 opacity background without changing the opacity of the text (just using "box2" and "box2 a" didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Here is example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code not output right way this is the right html code :

```
<body>
 <header>
 <div class="topbox">
 <ul>
 <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </header>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="scrollbtn"><img src="Images/Scroll.png" style="width:40%"/>     
</div>
<div class="bgbox">
<div class="box2">
<a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">© 2017 "TEXT" All Rights Reserved</div>
</div>
</body>
```

the `header` tag must be within `body` tag

2nd thing i tried your code with footer position : absolute;
and works good for me

[image]

Comment: It works for me too as long as the content (Lorem ipsum...) is short but if I make it longer the footer stays in the middle :/

Comment: I really don't  , but because this is just simple you can use the @vadiser answer as source and starting from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to tag him to this but I would like Edward D for finding the answer ! 
I first tried deleting all "**height:100%**;" wich didn't fix the problem right away but was clearly an error from me as it made "**.body**" and "**.html 100%**" the resolution thus making all other "**position:absolute**;" divs move according to it.
But the real problem was Bgbox being in absolute too. As soon as I made it "**position:relative;**" the "#footer" positioned itself according to it. Thank you very much Edward D and all those who tried to help !

Comment: Here's how to "accept" the answer that was most helpful to you, which will give the answerer reputation and also help people searching with similar questions to find what's useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.   If you still need help with half-opaque background sizee to match fully-opaque text, start a new question and we'll help :)

Comment: Thank you my half-opaque background works like a charm (funny phrase cause I don't believe in charms) but if I ever need help I'll come here ! Great site and great people. Question answered in less than 30mns and problem solved in a few hours. Hurray!